# Pandas: compare two columns where one has NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below:

```
        Date             A        B
2022-05-01 08:00:00      43       100
2022-05-01 08:01:00      NaN      54
2022-05-01 08:02:00      41       100
```

I will like to filter the rows if:

1. Column `A` is NaN
2. Column `B` is < 100

I tried this line of code:

```
dff = df.loc[((df[df['A'].isna()]) & (df['B'] < 100))]
```

However I get an error:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

I think the error is pretty clear (I can't compare A with B due to different data type?)

Is there a way to compare the two columns and ideally to add a new column with comments for every filtered rows?

The expected output is:

```
        Date             A        B       Comments
2022-05-01 08:01:00      NaN      54      Damaged item
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem in your Code Snippet:

Before moving towards a solution let's discuss the problem in your `Code Snippet`:

- The primary reason for `Code Breaking` is the `Return` type of your `Conditions`:

  1. `df['A'].isna()` will return `bool` values
  2. `[df['B'] < 100]` will return a `Data`
- So, according to the above condition we can't compare `Bool` and `Float`

> To know more about **pd.dataFrame.isna()**: [Click Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)

#### Solution :

Now, let's deep dive into the `Solution` of your given Scenario.

- The easiest way to `solve` such an error is that we have to use `Conditions` in which the `return` would be the same for both conditions. So, here I have used the `lt` operator to compare values that `return bool` based on the condition.

So, for detailed solution refer the `Code Snippet` mentioned below:

```
# Import all the important Modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data Regenration
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2022-05-01 08:00:00', '2022-05-01 08:01:00', '2022-05-01 08:02:00'],
    'A': [43, np.nan, 41],
    'B': [100, 54, 100]
})

# Condition for 'Damage Items'
conditions = [
    (data_df['A'].isna() & data_df['B'].lt(100))
]

# 'Choice' to return when above 'Condition' is true
choices = ['Damaged item']

# Store Results
data_df['Comments'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='')
```

```
# Output of above 'Code'
    Date                 A        B     Comments
0   2022-05-01 08:00:00  43.0     100   
1   2022-05-01 08:01:00  NaN      54    Damaged item
2   2022-05-01 08:02:00  41.0     100
```

> To know more about **np.select()**: [Click Here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)